# Vaadin: Auto click button after on return key

Tags: java, vaadin

As the LoginForm is no longer present in Vaadin 7, what is the best approach to handle a basic login page consisting of a single username/password input and a "login" button.

How can I make sure that when hitting the return key the form is submitted? I can think of ways of doing this, but figured there must be a more common approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Vaadin 13+

In Vaadin Flow versions 13 and later, use [`Button::addClickShortcut`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/13.0.13/com/vaadin/flow/component/ClickNotifier.html#addClickShortcut-com.vaadin.flow.component.Key-com.vaadin.flow.component.KeyModifier...-). The method in defined in the interface [`com.vaadin.flow.component.ClickNotifier`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/13.0.13/com/vaadin/flow/component/ClickNotifier.html).

This `addClickShortcut` method replaces the `setClickShortcut` (*add* vs *set*) in Vaadin 7 & 8 as seen in [other correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23777962/642706).

```
Button login = new Button("Login");  
login.addClickListener(click -> {
    //do your things here 
});       
login.addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER);  //  Bind keyboard shortcut.
```

This code binds your [ENTER key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key) to the event listener.

Answer (score 9):

One simple way would be to use the LoginForm add on.
https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/loginform

The other way would be to just display a form with login&password fields and set the Login button as the default action.

In Vaadin 7:

```
// Have an Login button and set it as the default button
Button login = new Button("Login");
login.setClickShortcut(ShortcutAction.KeyCode.ENTER);  // Bind ENTER key to this button.
login.addStyleName(Reindeer.BUTTON_DEFAULT);           // Add styling as visual cue this button is the default button (has Enter key bound to it).
```

Vaadin 8 uses a different theme by default, *Valo* instead of *Reindeer*, using a different style name:

```
// Have an Login button and set it as the default button
Button login = new Button("Login");
login.setClickShortcut(ShortcutAction.KeyCode.ENTER); // Bind ENTER key to this button.
login.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_PRIMARY);         // Add styling as visual cue this button is the default button (has Enter key bound to it).
```

See documentation on *Shortcut Keys* [for Vaadin 7](https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/advanced/advanced-shortcuts.html) and [for Vaadin 8](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-shortcuts.html). Note that some web browsers may not support some keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Is the last line even related to the question?

Comment: Yes, it is. It adds styling for the button to show what is the default button/action